# Многоуровневый массив javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Мне нужно получить данные из массива, массив выглядит так:

[image: массив]

И мне нужно в цикле получать act из каждого массива

```
function setAllMap(map, act) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayhome.length; i++) {
        console.log(arrayhome[i][act]);
    }
}
```

Пытался сделать так, но ничего не получается

Comment: Покажите как вызываете. Вроде должно сработать если передать в функцию вторым параметром "act". Также текст того что выводится в консоль может все прояснть

Comment: Добавить фрагмент массива в ваш вопрос, то что я вижу на скриншоте - "объект" и доступ в таком случает через object[key].value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего
var act is not defined.
Попробуй `arrayhome[i]['act']`

Comment: У него там act параметром в функцию передается, возможно так и задумано)

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с массивами и коллекциями есть отличные инструменты [lodash](https://lodash.com/) и underscore
Итерация по свойствам объекта:

```js
var arrayhome = [{ act: 1 },{ act: 2 }] 
for(var i in arrayhome) {
      if (arrayhome.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if(arrayhome[i].act){
          document.write(arrayhome[i].act)
      }    
   }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но уже помогло ['act']

Comment: @Tit6ka ok. удачи в работе.

Comment: спасибо, js все больше привлекает разнообразными методами